# Serilog LogContext and custom args don't combine

Tags: serilog

Is there a way to mix custom serilog args and LogContext properties? I have looked through the docs but it doesn't seem to be mentioned.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message} [{Properties}]{NewLine}")
            .CreateLogger();

        using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 5))
        {
            Log.Information("Message using context {A}");

            var b = 1;
            Log.Information("Message usign context {A} and custom {b}", b);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output

```
//output: 
//2017-11-14 15:47:03 [Information] Message using context 5 [{}]
//2017-11-14 15:47:54 [Information] Message usign context 1 and custom {b} [{}]
```

Expected output

```
//output: 
//2017-11-14 15:47:03 [Information] Message using context 5 [{}]
//2017-11-14 15:47:54 [Information] Message usign context 5 and custom 1 [{}]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Serilog's API, any method that accepts a message template expects an exact number of matching arguments.

Serilog won't blow up if the number of placeholders in the template and the provided argument count doesn't match, but there's no guarantee this will work predictably - as you see here.

So in this case, it's necessary to include both `A` and `b` in the arguments to `Information()` in order to get the output you expect.

Comment: I think I would be okay with that. But then why is {A} not shown as an attached property? Serilog must not just match number of arguments as swapping {b} and {A} order in the message gives the desired output. `Log.Information("Message usign custom {b} and context {A}", b);` puts the correct values in the correct place...

Comment: That's the thing :-) ... what Serilog does when argument counts don't match is not intended to be relied upon. It'll match left-right, but could change in future and YMMV if depending upon it. HTH!

Comment: (As an example, you'll get totally different behavior if the template contains `{0}` numeric placeholders rather than named ones.)